# Using JdbcTemplate in a parallel stream

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

JdbcTemplate is Autowired from Spring in SpringBoot
How do I configure to support multiple threads, for example when it is in a parallalStream()? Is there an option to always create new connection when calling it?

Answer (score 1):

JdbcTemplate acquires connections from DataSource. You can get different behavior with different DataSource implementations.

*SimpleDriverDataSource* creates new connection on every call.

For better performance you can use connection pooling DataSource. With connection pooling several connections can be reused between queries and used in parallel. Check out, for example, HikariCP or C3PO.

[SimpleDriverDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SimpleDriverDataSource.html)

[A Simple Guide to Connection Pooling in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling)

[Configuration Connection Pool in SpringBoot](https://medium.com/programming-sharing/configuration-connection-pool-in-springboot-c561b5b90b99)

[Connection to a Production Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)